My flutter login Page gives this error, Null check operator used on a null value See also: https:/'flutter.dev/ docs/testing/errors
I am developing a PLant Disease Detection app using Flutter, and despite my best efforts, I encountered an unexpected error. I am creating a login page for my disease detection app, below is my code. I have tried multiple solutions but My flutter login Page gives this error,

Null check operator used on a null value See also: https:/'flutter.dev/ docs/testing/errors.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'home.dart'; // Import your home screen or wherever you want to navigate after successful login

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DatabaseReference _dbRef =
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("plant_health_users");
  bool _isObscure = true;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/login.png'),
                  height: height * 0.2,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Welcome Back',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Make it work, make it right, make it fast',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
                Form(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: emailController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_outlined),
                            labelText: 'Email',
                            hintText: 'xyz@gmail.com',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          ),
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: _isObscure,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                                });
                              },
                              icon: Icon(_isObscure
                                  ? Icons.visibility
                                  : Icons.visibility_off),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 40.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _login();
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                              ),
                              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xff148865),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white70),
                              padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                            ),
                            child: _isLoading
                                ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                  Colors.white),
                            )
                                : Text(
                              'Login'.toUpperCase(),
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                letterSpacing: 1.2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _login() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true; // Set loading state to true
    });

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      if (userCredential.user != null) {
        bool userExists =
        await checkIfUserExists(emailController.text);
        if (userExists) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
          );
        } else {
          // Show a dialog or snackbar to inform the user that the account does not exist
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle login errors (e.g., invalid email/password, user not found)
      print("Login error: $e");
      // Show a dialog or snackbar to inform the user about the error
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false; // Clear loading state
      });
    }
  }

  Future<bool> checkIfUserExists(String email) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;
    try {
      dataSnapshot = await _dbRef
          .orderByChild("email")
          .equalTo(email)
          .once()
          .then((event) {
        return event.snapshot;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error fetching data: $error");
      return false;
    }
    Object? values = dataSnapshot.value;
    return values != null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


The error should tell you on which variable the problem is, can you add the full error you are getting?
